# How can I add a PNG image to Tumblr blog links?

Tags: tumblr

I have a Tumblr and where are my Home and Ask links I want to put a PNG image with the words of the font I want. But I want the link to redirect to what I've originally put in the links of the blog. What should I add in the HTML to manage do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible.

What you can do is create your png images and then upload them to tumblr here: http://www.tumblr.com/themes/upload_static_file

Make a note of the file link. Then in your theme you can code the links to have images instead of text.

This will depend on your theme to some extent, but it could look something like this:

```
 <a href="/">
    <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/yourfile.png" />
 </a>
 <a href="/ask">
    <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/yourfile2.png" />
 </a>
```